# CRM 2011: How to publish the duplicate detection rules in dynamic crm 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-4

I Published duplicate detection rules in one week back, but still it is publishing in dynamic crm 2011,can anyone tell me what is the reason behind this.

Comment: I'm betting http://www.madronasg.com/blog/duplicate-detection-rules-automatically-unpublished solves your problem, but otherwise, you probably want to clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you perhaps provide some more details here. Are you saying that you published and the publishing process itself is still running a week later? If so I would suggest the process has crashed an you may need to perform an iisreset and try again.

Or am I misunderstanding what you mean here? Some more details would help to better understand the problem.

Comment: you are right man,publishing process itself is still running a week later

Comment: @Hashim Hi Hashim, if that is the case then I would certainly conclude that the publishing process has failed and you would need to try it again (probably after the iisreset). Let me know if that solves the issue. If it looks like taking so long again, I would take a look at the changes made to see if there is a problem with the metadata. On a separate point, the link provided by Peter is useful when considering duplicate detection rules and worth looking out for.

Comment: Hi philip after the iisreset also its still in 'Publishing' Mode, can you help me to find out the problems with the metadata.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: restart the 'Microsoft Dynamics CRM Asynchronous Processing Service'

Ofter happens when you go into system jobs or want to run bulk deletion and statuts indicates 'waiting for ressources'